# if statement referencing foreign key

Tags: python, django

I have django app where technicians enter service data, and if the customer is not in the list they choose "NEW" from the `customer` field dropdown and enter the new customer's name in the `service.new_customer` field rather than adding the customer. When I display it, I want to show "John's Pub" if it's an existing customer, and "NEW: John's Pub" if it's not.  I can get this to work by using the id - the id for the customer called "NEW" is 1038.  But, I want to be able to have the logic reference the word "NEW" rather than the id.

Here is my `models.py`

```
class Service(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    new_customer = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

This `view.py` works:

```
def service_view(request):
    for service in services:
        if service.customer_id == 1038:
            service.customer_combo="%s:%s"%(service.customer,service.new_customer)
        else:
            service.customer_combo="%s"%(service.customer)
return render(request,'template.html')
```

This `view.py` does not work*:

```
def service_view(request):
    for service in services:
        if service.customer == 'NEW':
            service.customer_combo="%s:%s"%(service.customer,service.new_customer)
        else:
            service.customer_combo="%s"%(service.customer)
return render(request,'template.html')
```

- When I say it doesn't work, I mean it only assigns customer.combo in the "else" condition, though there are tons of cases where the customer is NEW - it's printing "NEW" rather than "NEW:John's Pub"

How should I be constructing the 'if service.customer == 'NEW':' statement to get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if service.customer.name == 'NEW':`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare a `Customer` object with the `name` of the customer. They are of different types and cannot be compared.

You need to do something like:

```
service.customer == some_customer_object # compare with model object
```

or

```
service.customer.name == 'NEW' # compare with the name
```

or

```
str(service.customer) == 'NEW' # compare with the representation of the object
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you for pointing that out.  I get stuck on this a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This works too, but I think Peter's answer is better, it just seems cleaner

```
if str(service.customer) == 'NEW':
```